# gradle compile filetree syntax

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

folder structure:

```
- RootProject Folder
  - MyMainProject
  - MyLibraries
       - Facebook
```

The root project folder has a build.gradle file, but MyMainProject has the one with all the dependencies.

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
     compile project(':MyLibraries:Facebook')
}
```

I feel like `compile project` doesn't have the correct path. Is there a way to make it look up a directory, so something like `../MyLibraries/Facebook`? I don't completely understand the colon (:) syntax

Comment: :MyLibraries:Facebook means that you have a folder called MyLibraries, and inside that folder you have a library project/folder called Facebook.  I am also assuming that your build.gradle file is inside of RootProject folder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `settings.gradle`, and the dependency presumably needs to be declared as `project(':Facebook')`. (According to the folder structure, `MyLibraries` and `Facebook` are siblings.) For more information, see the multi-project builds chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html). I don't understand why you think this is connected to the `fileTree` syntax, and I don't see `libs` in your folder structure.

Comment: I modified my structure to show more, looks like some formatting got lost when I originally posted it

Comment: Do you have a `settings.gradle`, and what are its contents?